# rest assured to match value from a root json array

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

Am new to rest assured

I have a json response like this

```
{
  "queryPath": "/api/",
  "nId": "f084f5ad24fcfaa9e9faea0",
  "statusCode": 707
  "statusMessage": "Success",
  "results": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "10248522500798",
        "capabilities": [
          "men",
          "women"
        ],
        "name": "errt2"
      },
      {
        "id": "418143778",
        "capabilities": [
          "dog",
          "cat"
        ],
        "name": "Livin"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

String type = "men"
Using rest assured i need to check the type value men with capabilities array values

```
[
          "men",
          "women"
        ]
```

and

```
"capabilities": [
          "dog",
          "cat"
        ]

    If the type value `men` not contains in any of the capabilities i need to raise error..how it is possible?
```

i used following code .But it is not working.any other way??

```
body("results.data.capabilities", hasItems(type));
```

Am getting error

```
Expected: (a collection containing "men")
  Actual: [[ men,women
        ], [dog, cat]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your jsonPath

```
results.data.capabilities
```

points to both "capabilities" arrays since they are nested at the same level of your JSON.  If you can reliably expect the first "capabilities" array to contain "men" then you can specify the first "capabilities" in your jsonPath like so:

```
results.data.capabilities[0]
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that the order of the elements in the array might differ. You can also select one element, for example on the `id` property, and assert that one: `body("results.data.find { it.id == '10248522500798' }.capabilities", hasItems(type));`

Comment: @marcok but it says `it` not defined? When I apply your syntax. I think rest assured should provide more details about this in the official doc...... I cannot find a way to assert the root element.